# How to access and modify the IE printer settings from VB.NET per application

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

I am using a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control in my application. I am population some content into it and calling its `Print` method. This method uses the default margin settings from IE and printing the document. I would like to programmatically change the margin values before printing it? (The default values in IE should not be modified)

I have checked all the properties in the WebBrowser class and could not find any methods that will allow me to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313723

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236777